# As of today (2015-Nov) how many different anonymous type altcoins are there?

Tags: altcoin, privacy

How many anonymous type altcoins are there out as of 2015-Nov? Also what were their release dates and community size? I'd like to get into an anonymous coin, but I'm unsure which one has the most activity and community support.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few I have heard of, some are in development some are already being used.

- ZeroCoin:
  http://zerocoin.org/

whitepaper:
http://zerocash-project.org/paper

> The road ahead
>
> The plan is to make an altcoin, powered by the new Zerocash Protocol,
>   that provides consumers with the financial privacy they expect from
>   debit cards, credit cards, and cash. To do this, we plan on release a
>   working, non research code quality client based off the bitcoin 0.9.1
>   codebase integrating the new Zerocash protocol.

- Monero:
  https://getmonero.org/home

> WHAT IS MONERO ? Monero is a secure, private, untraceable currency. It
>   is open-source and freely available to all.
>
> With Monero, you are your own bank. Only you control and are
>   responsible for your funds, and your accounts and transactions are
>   kept private from prying eyes.
>
> Want to find out more? An overview of Monero's main features are
>   below. If you'd like to try Monero for yourself the Getting Started
>   section is an excellent launching point.

- ShadowCash:
  http://aboutshadow.com/

> SHADOWCORE
>
> An entire privacy-based platform which aims to establish an anonymous
>   economy, with multiple features that give people all the financial
>   freedom and privacy they should have.
>
> Shadow is a decentralized anonymous communication, commerce and
>   currency platform through which the virtual currency, ShadowCash, can
>   be transferred. One of the significant advantages of Shadow is its
>   deep integration with the rest of Shadow's features as well as
>   offering native TOR support for IP obfuscation.

- DashCoin:
  http://dashcoin.net/

> Dashcoin (DSH) is an automatically mutating anonymous cryptocurrency
>   Dashcoin is a Next generation anonymous cryptocurrency and the first
>   automatically mutating cryptocurrency created with CryptoNote
>   technology. What does this really means? Our network code is always up
>   to date with minimal developer cost and close to 0% errors. You are no
>   longer depending on developers good will. Concentrate less on
>   developers and more on your trades and projects.

- Here seems to be page that has gathered a few more anonymous altcoins:
  http://www.altcoinfever.com/anonymous-cryptocurrency-altcoin/

As for the size of any of these communities, that I am unsure of. I just wanted to present you with options I have found. I cannot guarantee the validity of any of these altcoins and their claims of anonymity.